# Passing pointer to a function in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I wrote the following piece of code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void temp (int * x)
{
    x=new int [2];
    x[0]=1;
    x[1]=2;
}

int main()
{
    int *ptr;
    temp(ptr);
    cout<<ptr[0]<<endl;
    cout<<ptr[1]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Running it gives seg fault, so is the memory allocation which happens inside `temp` function  local to function? The memory gets deallocated while returning from `temp`? I know, that to solve this problem, I need to pass pointer to pointer `ptr`, but still, why exactly does this thing not work?

Comment: Note that the use of `<iostream>`, `using namespace std`, `new`, `std::cout`, `operator <<` and `std::endl` mean that your program is C++ rather than C

Comment: Please remember, you should almost never handle memory manually in C++. I.e. no `new` or `delete` operators at all. Only STL containers and smart pointers.

Comment: and don't forget to `delete[]`

Comment: sorry its C++, not C... :)

Comment: @Mikhail: There will definitely be times you want to use `new`.  I'd agree about `delete`; at least in C++11, `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` effectively automate deletion.  But you still have to initialize them somehow.

Comment: Memory allocations are never local, there's only one heap and it's exists for the whole peogram. What is local is the assignment to x, that has no effect on ptr in main. Also no memory is freed in your code, since there are no calls to delete. So it has a memory leak.

Comment: @john: Eh.  "The heap" is an implementation detail.  There doesn't have to be *any* heap, let alone only one.  A compiler could make it so each function gets its own heap if it wanted to.

Comment: @cHao If that was so, then how would one function be able to free memory allocated in another? There is only one heap because there is only one operator new and one operator delete.

Comment: @john: There's no mandatory representation of a pointer either.  It could include information about the heap used to allocate the memory.  Or, the memory could have some stuff before it saying what heap to use.  (Many implementations already add some stuff in the addresses right before the pointee; why couldn't a heap pointer be among that stuff?)

Comment: @cHao Now you are the one getting lost in implementation details. There is notionally only one place (often called the heap) upon which new and delete operate. Who cares if this is actually implemented as one heap, multiple heaps or as something entirely different

Comment: @john: You're the one saying "there's only one heap".  That's not some meaningless word you're tossing around, and it's not a synonym for "dynamic storage duration".  It's the name of a data structure for managing memory.  And there can be zero, one, two, or a thousand of them.

Comment: @john: That's not even getting into the fact that each class can have its own `new` and `delete` operators, or that the global versions of them can be replaced virtually at will by running code.  Or the existence of `std::get_temporary_buffer` and `std::return_temporary_buffer`.  Etc.

Comment: @cHao You have `make_unique` and `make_shared` for these purposes.

Comment: @Mikhail: Isn't the whole point of that post that we *don't* have `make_unique` yet, so someone decided to play around and make one?  :)

Answer (score 2):

C++ answer:

You are passing the `int*` argument into `temp` by value. This means that you are copying `ptr` into the function, and the pointer `x` is a completely separate object. You then assign the result of `new int[2]` to this copy, but the `ptr` in `main` is left unaffected. To be able to modify the pointer passed as an argument, you need to take it by reference:

```
void temp (int*& x)
{ 
  // ...
}
```

This means that `x` now refers to the pointer that is passed as an argument. The alternative solution here is to return an `int*` instead:

```
int* temp()
{
    int* x = new int [2];
    x[0]=1;
    x[1]=2;
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    int *ptr = temp();
    // ...
}
```

However, the caller of `temp` might be unclear about the ownership of the `int` object. They need to `delete[]` it, but this isn't made explicit in the interface. Instead, you can return a `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

To alter something in a function in C, you need to pass a pointer to it. In this case, you want to alter a pointer, so you need a pointer to a pointer:

```
void temp (int** x)
```

then in the function use `*x` where you now have `x` (you will need `(*x)[n]`, as `*x[n]` means something else)

Then call `temp` with:

```
temp(&ptr);
```

This should solve it in C, and will work in C++.

In C++, you could also pass a reference to a pointer:

```
 void temp(int*&x)
```

which will allow the syntax you have already to be used unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

Think about this code

```
void temp(int x)
{
    x = 2;
}

int main()
{
    int y = 3;
    temp(y);
    cout << y << '\n';
}
```

What the output going to be `2` or `3`? Of course it's three. Now what's the difference between this and your example? Nothing at all. Unless you use a reference everything in C++ is passed by value. `x` is a *copy* of `y`, so changes to `x` *never* affect `y`. This is true whetever the types involved, its true of ints and its true of pointers.

Comment: I rather like the simplicity and relative jargon-free-ness of this explanation.  Well, that and the fact that it makes pointers look less mysterious.  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
int *ptr;
```

You created an automatic variable here and you passed it to

```
temp(ptr);
```

This is pass by copy so `x` will get the value of `ptr` and `x` scope is within the `temp` function. It is an automatic variable in that scope.When you return from `temp` its value is lost.
Now, the memory allocated and pointed to by `x`  is in no way reflected to `ptr` in main. (**They are not connected**)

You need to do `temp(int*& ptr)` i.e. pass by reference. Or `temp(int** ptr)` i.e. pass by address

<sub>Note: You have a memory leak in your `temp`</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a ** because you are allocating x inside of your function.

Comment: It's C++, so `void temp(int*& x)` is better than an `int**`.

Comment: I missed seeing iostream and looked at the post title that asked for a solution in C.